# Why does my Iframe lose its content when I execute JavaScript from within the frame to "slide" it's parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slider

I am new to learning js and having a problem with the following:

I have a custom block on my page that looks like this...

```
<div id="chat">
  <iframe src="/sites/all/libraries/webim/client.php?locale=en"
  height="100%" width="100%">
  </iframe>
</div>

<div class="slider">
<a class="toggleup" href="#">Live Support</a>
</div>
```

And a function in my script.js file that looks like this...

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".toggleup").click(function(){
    jQuery("#chat").slideToggle("slow");
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("toggledown");return false;
  });
});
```

The issue at hand is that client.php returns 2 variations of a page, both of which contain close buttons that execute:

```
javascript:window.close();
```

Which I have changed to:

```
javascript:window.parent.jQuery('.toggleup').click()
```

When the JavaScript is executed, the chatbox slides closed as it should, but then all I see is:

```
[object Object]
```

where my Iframe content should be.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had these two elements in my custom block and both needed to be executed for everything to work.

```
<div id="chat">
  <iframe src="/sites/all/libraries/webim/client.php?locale=en"
  height="100%" width="100%">
  </iframe>
</div>

<div class="slider">
<a class="toggleup" href="#">Live Support</a>
</div>
```

However when calling the jQuery function like this...

```
javascript:window.parent.jQuery('.toggleup').click()
```

instead of clicking the link, the box would close as expected but the div and iframe are never created.

Instead I changed the following line in my custom block from...

```
<a class="toggleup" href="#">Live Support</a>
```

to...

```
<a class="toggleup" href="#" id="chatbtn">Live Support</a>
```

and called it using

```
parent.document.getElementById('chatbtn').click();
```

instead of the previous jQuery code therefore executing everything in my custom block and not just the jQuery for closing the slide.

Hope it helps someone.
:

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you are trying to do :).

All I can say for now is that using inline tags for scripts is not a good idea, try to enhance the page from inside the script.js. Are you trying to fire the click on the .toggleup with `.click()`? This won't work since the `.click()` function registers a handler for the selected object(s) - in this case you are adding an undefined handler as there are no arguments supplied. If you want to trigger the event on the element use `.trigger('click');` instead. The `[object Object]` thingy is the string representation of an object so I think somehow you assign a stringified object to the iframes src.

Thats all I can say for now, if you specify a little more what you want to do I will try to help you :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. If you would like to see what it is I am trying to get at you can see the problem on my page at iinqllc dot com. All I am trying to do is slide the chat box closed from within the frame.

Comment: Hmm I see the close button inside the chat window and when I click it it will collapse. But if I try to open it again it won't have the right size ... so it kinda works, but I don't exactly see why :). You could try to swap `javascript:window.parent.jQuery('.toggleup').click()` with `window.parent.jQuery('.toggleup').trigger('click');`

Comment: Still produces the same behavior if I omit "javascript:" the frame shows a duplicate of the whole site in the frame. I'll continue to use the .trigger method any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry right now I don't see a good solution, I don't know how e.g. facebook handles his chat window, have you had a look on this one with firebug? All I see is that on my system with chrome your chat window closes as I would expect it ... this doesn't seem to work cross browser.